# Adding colour to specific rows SQL, PHP, Access

Tags: php, sql, colors, row

I'm trying to sort a database for high priority alerts.  My goal was to get the higher priority alerts at the top of the page ('O' and 'P') and the lower priority alerts at the bottom of the page.  Also I wanted the id in descending order for the entire display page.  Now I'm trying to add colour to the rows which have a status that equals to O or P.
I have the code over here for the adjustment of the high priority status alerts:

```
$sql = odbc_exec($odbc," 
       SELECT * 
         FROM tblOpslog
        Where Deleted = No ".$criteria."
          AND Noview = No
          AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')
        ORDER BY iif(status IN ('O', 'P'), 1, 2), opslogid DESC"
       ) or die (odbc_errormsg());
```

Can anyone make any suggestions to the code in which I can add a shade of colour to the rows in which the statuses are O and P.

Please note that this is a php file using an Access database with SQL queries.  Also this code is working fine so I'm not looking to change this code, rather add something to it that displays a colour for the entire row.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this:

```
if($row['status'] == "O"){
    $color = "red";      
}
    elseif($row['status'] == "P"){
    $color = "green";
}
```

Comment: Of-course, you must make it adapt your code. This is just the correct method of how you can do it.

Comment: I did do that.  It gives me this error when I run it in the browser

Comment: $sql = odbc_exec($odbc,"SELECT * FROM tblOpslog Where Deleted = No ".$criteria." AND Noview = No ORDER BY iif(status IN ('O', 'P') and (ResolvedID = 0), 1, 2), opslogid DESC") 

if($row['status'] == "O"){
    $color = "red";      
}
    elseif($row['status'] == "P"){
    $color = "green";
}

Comment: Sorry I'm a new programmer please bare with me.

Comment: Hmm, it won't work if you just copy and paste. I only done that code to give you the method of how its done. You might need to get someone to help you put it together.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this;
I didn't test it

```
//Your query and while loop
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {   
if($row['status'] == "O"){
        $color = "red";      
    }
        elseif($row['status'] == "P"){
        $color = "green";
    }

echo "<div id=".$color.">".$row['status']."</div>";
```

And in your css just something like this:

```
#red{
   background-color:red;
}
```